# Get reports from maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9:dependencies

Tags: rabbitmq, licensing

I added plugin in my `pom.xml`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </plugin>
```

I would like to generate raport about licenses of dependency in my project.
How to do it ?
Launching goal: `info-reports-plugin:dependencies` by IDEA doesn't help. It returns in console:

> [INFO] --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9:dependencies
>   (default-cli) @ myApp [WARNING] The repository url
>   'http://download.java.net/maven/2' is invalid - Repository
>   'm2.dev.java.net' will be blacklisted. [WARNING] The repository url
>   'http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository' is invalid -
>   Repository 'apache.snapshots' will be blacklisted.

I can't see anywhere report.